# Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) Autofill Style

Tags: css, google-chrome, autofill

Updated Chrome today and the style of the Username / Password fields have changed.

I have a dropdown which I don't remember seeing before.

Styling input:-webkit-autofill does nothing. 
Also tried just input:autofill to see if it has come out of prefixing.

Anybody know what changed recently? 
(A scan of the release notes suggests only security changes since the start of December but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place.)

Note: I want the autofill behaviour, I just don't want it to overwrite my input styles.

[image: example auto fill]